# How do I get the month number with the maximum number of days from the date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 10 million rows, where there are two columns that contain the start date and the end date of the range. For example, 2019-09-25 and 2019-10-20. I want to extract the month number with the maximum number of days, in this example it will be 10. In addition to dates that are separated by one month, there are also such examples: 2019-07-01 and 2019-07-29 (within one month), as well as 2019-07-01 and 2019-09-05 (more than one month). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(EndDate),MONTH(EndDate),1),EndDate) >= DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EOMONTH(StartDate)) THEN DATEPART(MONTH,EndDate)
            ELSE DATEPART(MONTH,StartDate)
       END
FROM (VALUES('20190925','20191020'))V(StartDate,EndDate);
```

Comment: This does not work for a period, for example ,from '20190925' to '20191120', returns 11 instead of 10.

Comment: Neither of those values have the month `10` in them though, @Rabbit . The months are `11` and `09`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
with
l0(n) as (
    select 1 n 
    from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as v(n))
select top(1) with ties
       vTable.*, calc.dt month_with_most_days
from (values ('20190925','20191020'),
             ('20190925','20191120')) vTable(startdate, enddate)
      cross apply (values (datediff(month, vTable.startdate, vTable.enddate))) diff(mo_count)
      cross apply (select top (diff.mo_count+1)
                          row_number() over (order by (select null)) n
                   from l0 l1, l0 l2, l0 l3, l0 l4) tally /* 8^4 months possible */
      cross apply (values (cast(case when tally.n=1 then startdate
                                     when tally.n=diff.mo_count+1 then enddate
                                    else eomonth(dateadd(month, tally.n-1, startdate)) end as date))) calc(dt)
order by row_number() over (partition by startdate, enddate
                            order by day(calc.dt) desc);
```

```
startdate   enddate     month_with_most_days
20190925    20191020    2019-09-25
20190925    20191120    2019-10-31
```

Comment: This does not work for a period, for example ,from '20190925' to '20191120', returns 9 instead of 10.

Comment: @Rabbit, sorry to be chatty, there was another issue so I updated again.  Should be right now

Comment: I may not have formulated the question correctly, but the number of days in a month should be calculated based on the start and end dates of the range, for example, for the start date '20190925' there are only 6 days from 25 to 31, for the end date '20191020' - 20 days from 1 to 20, then the answer will be 10, and for the end date '20191120' - 20 days from 1 to 20 in November, but also 31 days in October from 1 to 31, then the answer will also be 10.

Comment: If the number of days is the same, then you need to return the nearest month to the start date.

Comment: @Rabbit are you set with an answer?  I could update this

Answer (score 0):

Does the following fit your requirements?

You can build a table of days-in-month (this would be permanent ideally)

and then join to it using the month numbers of your min and max dates.

```
declare @start date='20190925', @end date='20191020';
--declare @start date='20190701', @end date='20190729';
--declare @start date='20190701', @end date='20190905';
with dim as (
    select m,DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),m,1)  )+1, 0)))d
    from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))m(m)
)
select top(1) with ties m
from dim
where m between Month(@start) and Month(@end)
order by d desc
```

You don't state how you determin the most days where there are several months with the same number of months, so `with ties` includes all qualifying months.

**Edit**

So I don't know if there is a requirement to span years - the sample data suggests not - however with a permanent list of dates and corresponding days in month values (this is often part of a *calendar* table) a slight tweak will accomodate it.

```
with dim as (
    select Year(@start)*100 + m m, Day(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, DateFromParts(Year(@start),m,1)  )+1, 0)))d
    from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))m(m)
    union all
    select Year(@end)*100 + m m, Day(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, DateFromParts(Year(@end),m,1)  )+1, 0)))d
    from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))m(m)
)
select top(1) with ties m
from dim
where m between Year(@start)*100 + Month(@start) and Year(@end)*100 + Month(@end) 
order by d desc
```

Comment: I may not have formulated the question correctly, but the number of days in a month should be calculated based on the start and end dates of the range, for example, for the start date '20190925' there are only 6 days from 25 to 31, for the end date '20191020' - 20 days from 1 to 20, then the answer will be 10, and for the end date '20191120' - 20 days from 1 to 20 in November, but also 31 days in October from 1 to 31, then the answer will also be 10. If the number of days is the same, then you need to return the nearest month to the start date.